# Home workers requiring simultaneous office VPN and local network access

Tags: vpn, checkpoint

I now have a large number of remote users that are using a Check Point Secure Client VPN connection into the office. These users also need access to network resources attached to their local router/hub (network storage and network printer). Is there any way that the client (Windows 7 or XP) can be configured to bypass the VPN for local addresses (192.*)

Answer (score 1):

Same, not sure about checkpoint, but in Cisco vpn client settings there is a "allow local lan access"

Answer (score 0):

i don't know the check point vpn, but in f-secure it was possible to configure the vpn profile to only route some defined networks/subnets over the vpn.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like at this time, the answer is no.  The way this product works, when you connect to VPN, your IP address changes and the PC is no longer on the home LAN network.   Other answerers have noted that other products have configurations that work around this, but Check Point Secure Client VPN doesn't have one.